# UITableView cell title to transfer to a Uitextfield on another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uitableview, uitextfield

Is there a way to get the title of a UITableView cell to be carried to a UITextField on another screen when the cell is pressed?

So when the cell is pressed, another view opens, which has the uitextfield, and the title of the cell should be in the uitextfield. I have lots of these kinds of cell that need to work this way, so can somebody please help me?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: just create a `property` in the new `viewController`, `import` the new `viewController` in your `tableViewController`. when `cell` is tapped just set the `title` of the `cell` in the `property` of new `viewController`.

Comment: ow remember that u need a setter method too...

Answer (score 1):

Use a model. All the data in your application should be stored in a model. The view controllers bind the model data into the views.

MyModel.h

```
@interface MyModel : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@end
```

MyModel.m

```
@implementation MyModel
@end
```

MyTableViewController.h

```
…
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
…
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *models;
…
@end
…
```

MyTableViewController.m

```
…
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    MyModel *model = self.models[indexPath.row];

    // Bind model data to a cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = mode.title;
}
…
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    MyModel *model = self.models[indexPath.row];

    // Give the model to the details view controller.
    [segue.destinationViewController setModel:model];
}
…
```

MyDetailsController.h

```
…
@interface MyDetailsController : UITableViewController
…
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyModel *model;
…
@end
…
```

Now MyDetailsController has access model.title and can use it to assign values it's views.